# how to specify "excluded_fields" when using diff_against in simple_history in Django

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

I am using diff_against in simple_history in django.
See "history diffing" in simple_history docs:
`https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history_diffing.html`
I have this all working, but it states:
`"diff_against also accepts 2 arguments excluded_fields and included_fields to either explicitly include or exclude fields from being diffed."`
I can't figure out how to pass these fields. Here is what I have that is working (without any include or exclude fields):

```
def historical_changes(qry, id):
    changes = []
    if qry is not None and id:
        last = qry.first()
        for all_changes in range(qry.count()):
            new_record, old_record = last, last.prev_record
            if old_record is not None:
                delta = new_record.diff_against(old_record)
                changes.append(delta)
            last = old_record
    return changes
```

and I call it in a detail view using:

```
changes = historical_changes(hpn.history.all(), hpn.pk)
```

This all works. I then tried to incldue the "exclude_field". These are what I tried, but none worked:

```
delta = new_record.diff_against(old_record, excluded_fields('geom'))
or
delta = new_record.diff_against(old_record).excluded_fields('geom')
or
delta = new_record.diff_against(old_record.excluded_fields('geom'))
```

This is likley something quite simple, but I'm not figuring it out. Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use it like so:

```
delta = new_record.diff_against(old_record, excluded_fields=['geom'])
```

`diff_against` accepts a keyword argument `excluded_fields` rather than `excluded_fields` being a method of an `HistoricalRecords` class.